# JS and SVG. Getting child elements in a block by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have object block with svg file:

```
<object id="floor1_plan" type="image/svg+xml" data="map/map1.svg" height="100%" width="100%"></object>
```

Next I get content from this object:

```
var floor = document.getElementById("floor1_plan").contentDocument;
```

Inside this SVG block with id="floor" and child elements with id, tried to pull the id of these elements through:

```
var rooms = $('#floor').toArray().map(el => el.id);
```

but they are not attached to svg.

How to attach to svg and work directly inside it?

Comment: why not using SVG image as element directly? not sure I don't think this will work using `<object>`.

Comment: please check your code is the <script></script> on the top or bottom?

Comment: @Sidik, bottom, in separate file

Comment: try to console.log() variable , to see what cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

Find answer in

```
$(floor).find("#floor > *").toArray().map(el => el.id);
```